# Custom 404 page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want custom 404 page for my website. I already tried this code.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It's not working and showing "File not found error"

Custom 404 page is: https://www.hostitbro.in/404/

I am using this code in htaccess to remove .php from URLs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

I think this code conflict with 404 error htaccess code. anyone can fix this for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/abc/.*$
```

Comment: Now my code looks like this
```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 404 ^/404/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
``
doesn't work either